# Como solucionar el error de View [auth.login] not found - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

que tal tengo un problemas respecto a que no me cargan mis vistas en mi servidor, el error que me da es el siguiente View [auth.login] not found, de igual manera cuando pruebo con mis demas vistas no me reconocen y aparecen como si no encontraran, de forma local pero si normalmente me funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ejecutaste `php artisan make:auth`? Si lo hiciste, puede ser que hayas copiado otro proyecto y estás trabajando sobre ese, posiblemente debas ir a `bootstrap/cache` y renombrar `config.php por config.php_`, también puedes intentar con `php artisan view:clear` y `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Muchas gracias, por tu ayuda lo que comentaste me apoyo a solucionar ello.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya sido útil

Answer (score 2):

Mi solución fue la siguiente:

Dentro de mi proyecto ejecute el comando siguiente:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

siendo este archivo la raiz del problema porque no estaba publicado en:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez realizado esto de manera local, lo subi a mi servidor de nuevo, y a final al archivo dentro del servidor le cambie el nombre porque seguia persistiendo el problemas al siguiente:

en vez de config.php por **config.php_**